# R: How to web scrape a table across multiple pages with the same URL

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I would like to web scrape the table from: https://www.eurofound.europa.eu/observatories/emcc/erm/factsheets

This url doesnt change but the table has multiple pages.

I would like to do this in R and not using html_sessions() (since I reach a memory limit).

I get the first page using:

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.eurofound.europa.eu/observatories/emcc/erm/factsheets"
utils::download.file(url, destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)
input <- xml2::read_html("scrapedpage.html") 

table <- input %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(header=T)
```

Any help most appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 1838 pages to get. Example with the 10 first pages :

```
library(xml2)
library(RCurl)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

i=1
table = list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  data=getURL(paste0("https://www.eurofound.europa.eu/observatories/emcc/erm/factsheets","?page=",i))
  page <- read_html(data)
  table1 <- page %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "(//table)[2]") %>%
    html_table(header=T)
  i=i+1
  table1[[1]][[7]]=as.integer(gsub(",", "",table1[[1]][[7]]))
  table=bind_rows(table, table1)
  print(i)}

table$`Announcement date`=as.Date(table$`Announcement date`,format ="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Notes :

`i=1` : i is the variable to increment.
`table = list()` : to generate an empty list (mandatory for the first "bind_rows" step).
`1:10` : from first page to 10th page (should be 1:1838).
`paste0` : to generate each time a new URL.
`//table[2]` : the table of interest.
`as.integer(gsub)` : mandatory for the "bind_rows" step. Columns of each list to bind has to be the same type. Column 7 could be typed as character because of the `,`.
`print(i)` : to be informed of the progress.
`as.Date` : final step to convert the first column to the right type.

Other options : you could download all the pages outside the loop in an object, then process it. Maybe downloading all the pages with DTA then parse them in R would be faster.

Output :
[image: RScrape]