# Pulling in data from websites in R and diplaying them as R tables

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to build a financial dashboard in shiny and am stuck on the first step. I want to write a piece that reads in the following table

[image] from https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/

and displays it as a table in my shiny environment. Something like what I have below but the table should display contents form either of the links instead of random normal distributions.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "num", 
    label = "Choose a number", 
    value = 25, min = 1, max = 100),
  dataTableOutput("T")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$T <- renderDataTable({
    data.frame(x=rnorm(input$num))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scrape the table using `rvest` library in R.
You can install the package using
`install.packages("rvest")`.

To scrape the table you'll need to Inspect the webpage and find out the table id. It looks like this:

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url <- ("https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/")

page <- read_html(url)

stocks <- page %>%
  html_nodes('table#symbol-table') %>%
  html_table() %>% .[[1]]
```

And the whole Shiny App will look like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- ("https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/")

page <- read_html(url)

page

stocks <- page %>%
  html_nodes('table#symbol-table') %>%
  html_table() %>% .[[1]]

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "num", 
              label = "Choose a number", 
              value = 25, min = 1, max = 100),
  dataTableOutput("T")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$T <- renderDataTable({
    stocks
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: hey @Vishal A., this pulls in data only for the tickers whose names start with A. Do you know how I can get data for all tickers?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61603647) answer.